# Downloading files from the database in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm storing my files in the database and need to download a file when button clicked.
i can get the File content (Binary) in the action method. But how to return it as a file to the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("download file", "download") %>
```

and in your action:

```
public ActionResult Download() 
{
    byte[] contents = GetFileContentsFromDatabase();
    return File(contents, "image/jpeg")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return new FileContentResult(byte[], contentType)
```